# Query is getting a result I don't understand

Tags: mysql

I have this query which has to return everything from exercises.leerjaar = 1 but he also gives me the data about exercises.leerjaar = 2

I have tried to use IS NULL but that doesn't solve the problem completly

`SELECT exercises.* FROM exercises
WHERE exercises.leerjaar = 1 AND exercises.niveau = 1 OR exercises.niveau = 2 AND exercises.dimensie_id = 1`

The result I expect is

`exercises.leerjaar = 1 AND exercises.niveau = 1 OR exercises.niveau = 2 AND exercises.dimensie_id = 1`

but the result I get at the moment is

`exercises.leerjaar = 1 OR exercises.leerjaar = 2 AND exercises.niveau = 1 OR exercises.niveau = 2 AND exercises.dimensie_id = 1`

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and when doing that make sure you translate the dutch SQL table/column names into english, so they can understand it better..

Comment: But at first seight the problem seams to be [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)  and parenthesis related ... As `AND` is higher then `OR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE exercises.leerjaar = 1 
 AND (exercises.niveau = 1 OR exercises.niveau = 2) 
 AND exercises.dimensie_id = 1
```

Don't forget ton put parentheses around your "OR" conditions

PS : could you tell us exactly what you need as response data precisely ?

Comment: Why the parenthesis this way ? Maybe the topicstarter meant getting the results as `WHERE (exercises.leerjaar = 1 AND exercises.niveau = 1) OR (exercises.niveau = 2 AND exercises.dimensie_id = 1)` instead not clear without example data and expected results..

Comment: @Raymond nijland... I also agree the same thing. topic starter dosen't supply any clear requirement he just tell us that his query brings those data which are irrelevant to his thoughts.